# What queue do posts flagged 'Not An Answer' go?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, not-an-answer

I assume that when a post is flagged *`Very Low Quality`*, it goes in the [*Low Quality Posts*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) queue.  But, where do posts flagged as *`Not an Answer`* go?  Do they even end up in a queue, or are they only reviewed by moderators?

Answer (score 2):

They go to the low quality posts queue.

Comment: But moderators also have a queue that contains both types of flags.

Comment: not quite (not only) to LQP, see eg recent complaint at MSE: [Hide “not an answer” and “very low quality” flags in the moderator flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243145/165773)

Comment: @gnat Moderators *also* have the chance to act on the flags in parallel, yes, but they end up acting on a very small percentage.

Comment: "VLQ and NAA flags immediately enter the mod flag queue in all cases" ([quote source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/165773))

Comment: @gnat They enter those queues, yes, but they are very rarely acted on in those queues, which is exactly what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: if this was indeed rare, moderators likely wouldn't complain [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243145/165773)

Comment: @gnat He's requesting that the flags be hidden because as a mod he finds himself ignoring them in most cases.  In what way does this contradict the statement that the vast majority of these flags are handled by non-moderators?

Comment: "where do posts flagged as Not an Answer go? Do they even end up in a queue, or are they only reviewed by moderators?" - your answer as currently written is incomplete. It doesn't reflect the fact that flagged posts go into _two_ queues: LQP and moderators

Comment: @gnat The fact that moderators can see these flags, but, with only rare exceptions, don't actually act on them, means that it's not really relevant information.  It doesn't matter to the flagger that moderators have a queue of these items that they don't actually act on.  And if someone *really* cares that much about knowing every minuscule detail of the system, they have your comments to see that, even though almost nobody needs to care.

Comment: Regarding the "immediately enter the mod flag queue" quote, that's actually changed over the last few days. Shog9 is running an experiment to delay the presentation of "very low quality" flags, so now they are only shown to moderators after they have been presented to the community for an hour. If that works, I imagine longer durations and other flag types will be experimented with.

Comment: I believe there is also different behavior for answers that have upvotes, and/or have been accepted.